# How to create and add values to a standard lowercase analyzer in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, tokenize, analyzer, standardanalyzer

Ive been around the houses with this for the past few days trying things in various orders but cant figure out why its not working.

I am trying to create an index in Elasticsearch with an analyzer which is the same as the "standard" analyzer but retains upper case characters when records are stored.

I create my analyzer and index as follows:

```
PUT /upper
{
"settings": {
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
             "analyzer": {
                    "rebuilt_standard": {
                      "tokenizer": "standard",
                      "filter": [
                        "standard"   
                      ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "title": { 
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "rebuilt_standard"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then add two records to test like this...

```
POST /upper/doc
{
"text" : "TEST"
}
```

Add a second record...

```
POST /upper/doc
{
"text" : "test"
}
```

Using /upper/_settings gives the following:

```
{
  "upper": {
"settings": {
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": "5",
    "provided_name": "upper",
    "creation_date": "1537788581060",
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_standard": {
          "filter": [
            "standard"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    },
    "number_of_replicas": "1",
    "uuid": "s4oDgdsFTxOwsdRuPAWEkg",
    "version": {
      "created": "6030299"
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

But when I search with the following query I still get two matches! Both the upper and lower cases which must mean the analyser is not applied when I store the records.

Search like so...

```
GET /upper/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text": {
        "value": "test"
      }
  }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://localhost:9200/upper/_analyze?text=test&analyzer=rebuilt_standard

http://localhost:9200/upper/_analyze?text=TEST&analyzer=rebuilt_standard Can you provide the o/p of both api. replace localhost with your ES host if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first thing first you set your analyzer on the `title` field instead of upon the `text` field (since your search is on the text property, and since you are indexing doc with only `text` property)

```
"properties": {
    "title": { 
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "rebuilt_standard"
    }
}
```

try

```
"properties": {
    "text": { 
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "rebuilt_standard"
    }
}
```

and keep us posted ;)